# Calling object within object?

Tags: java, class, object

I am taking a Java class and the teacher isn't being very helpful with my question. The assignment is to create a hand of cards using the following tester class:

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // No pair
        System.out.println("No pair");
        Hand noPair1 = new Hand(new Card(10, 3), new Card(3, 0), new Card(13, 2), new Card(5, 1), new Card(14, 3));
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

There is a Hand class and a Card class:

```
public class Hand
{
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;
 
    public Hand()
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>(); // initialize cards
    }
}
```

Card Class:

```
public class Card
{
    
    // instance variables
    private final int rank; // card rank
    private final int suit; // card suit

    public Card(int rankIn, int suitIn)
    {
        rank = rankIn;
        suit = suitIn;
    }
```

My question: How do I get the Hand class to call the Card class from within the Hand class? The error is occurring on the line Hand noPair1 = new Hand(new Card(10,3), ...);

I am not allowed to change the Tester class.

Tried compiling and running the Tester class.

Comment: This is because you havn't defined a constructor suitable for your input, you only use the default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `new Hand(...)` you are calling a constructor of the `Hand` class. By the looks of it the only constructor for hand is a zero-arguments constructor. Namely, this one:

```
public Hand()
{
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>(); // initialize cards
}
```

There is no constructor for Hand that takes in a multiple cards as

```
Hand noPair1 = new Hand(new Card(10,3), ...)
```

would necessitate.

You have a couple options:

1. Add a new constructor to Hand that takes in a single `Card` (or using [varargs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs), multiple `Cards`). This would make the above snippet valid.
2. Make the `Hand`'s `cards` feild public, create a `Hand` instance with the existing zero-args constructor, and then add the cards to the `cards` feild after creating the hand.

Both of these have their advantages and disadvantages and there are of course many more ways to solve this - but those two are probably the simplest. If you cannot edit the test file, the first with `varargs` seems like your only option.

Comment: I believe the varargs is what I was looking for.

Comment: See also [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) post by Oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
    public Hand()
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>(); // initialize cards
    }
```

You only have the one constructor for `Hand`, but it's not a constructor that takes `Card`s.

You will need to add a constructor, or a method, to `Hand` that accepts some `Card`s.